# My VirtualBox Ubuntu crashed. How can I access its files from my Mac?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Ubuntu installed in my Mac using VirtualBox. A few minutes ago it crashed, so I have no access to Ubuntu now, but I need a file in it!

Is there any way I can access my Ubuntu files from my host OS (Mac), considering the fact that I can't run Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a ubuntu iso live cd from that virtual machine. You can access the file on disk from this live system.

Comment: +1 from me - that'd be the 1st thing to try - not sure what the 2nd thing would be :)

Comment: It worked. You saved me a lot of time buddy! Thanks a lot:-)